# Get next row td value of matched td value of a particular row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've tr's something like this..

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>6676</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>6582</td></tr>
<tr><td>33</td><td>6676</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>6614</td></tr>
<tr><td>95</td><td>6676</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>6619</td></tr>
```

When I click on some row, say 3rd row, I'll get a pop up with the details. In the pop up itself, I can navigate to previous record and next record as we have in gmail.

I'll get the second td using `find("td:eq(1)").text()`,

Now say I'm in 2nd record details in the modal window, and when I do it by catching the td value and matching it, it doesn't work. I should not use any counter for this. I'm just keeping all the records of the table in an array and fetching.
Here say currentMysqlId = 6676 I get on clicking on 3rd row. I need to get it row wise

var totalCount = parseInt(totalMsgs); // Total Number of Rows.

```
        for(var i = parseInt(divcurrentCount)+1; i <= parseInt(divcurrentCount)+10; i++){ 
            $('#tblInbox tbody tr:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('active'); // Add class to new page rows.
        }

        //displayActiveRows(); // Display active rows.
        var nextCount = (parseInt($("#currentRecord").val())+1);
        if(nextCount == parseInt(totalCount)) {
            $('#next').hide();              
        }
        $('#prev').show();
        // Fetch next mysqlContent ID because with that ID, the next record details will be fetched.
        var currentMysqlId = $("#currentMysqlId").val();


        //var nextMySqlId = $('#tblInbox tbody tr td:contains('+currentMysqlId+')').parent("tr").next("tr").find("td:eq(6)").text();
        var nextMySqlId = $('#tblInbox tbody tr td:contains('+currentMysqlId+')').parent().next().find("td:eq(6)").text();
        alert("next id::"+nextMySqlId);


        $('#divcurrentCount').html(nextCount);
        renderPopUpData(arrMsgs[nextMySqlId],0); // Display the appropriate data.
```

I'm getting stupid answers because if I search for 6676 in the table, it has many rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the whole script in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need `td:eq(1)` not `td:eq(6)`. also to get the clicked dom refernce you need to use `$(this)`:

```
$(this).parent().next().find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the question. The table has mutiple 6676, then it doesn't know which one it need to pickup. If the user has clicked on 3rd row, then 4th row td should be picked up..

Comment: @NizamAli: that is what it does. have you tried it. and obviously you will get the reference of clicked row in click handler for rows.

Comment: No.. I need to check the tr first on which it is clicked.. Its giving me same result

Comment: Its a navigation code from one record to another record.

Comment: // Fetch next mysqlContent ID because with that ID, the next record details will be fetched.
   var currentMysqlId = $("#currentMysqlId").val();
   
   
   //var nextMySqlId = $('#tblInbox tbody tr td:contains('+currentMysqlId+')').parent("tr").next("tr").find("td:eq(6)").text();
   var nextMySqlId = $('#tblInbox tbody tr td:contains('+currentMysqlId+')').parent().next().find("td:eq(6)").text();
   alert("iihiishd::"+nextMySqlId);

Comment: Your code still has `td:eq(6)`. Why `td:eq(6)`. Use `td:eq(1)` as suggested by @Milind

Comment: Yeah.. its just a snippet. My code has different tds

Comment: @NizamAli: that does not look like click handler

Comment: If you have a gmail contact let me know, I can show you the code what exactly it is.. because its a large one