# Get next row td value based on 3rd row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do navigation from one record to another record. I've tr's something like this..

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>6676</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>6582</td></tr>
<tr><td>33</td><td>6676</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>6614</td></tr>
<tr><td>95</td><td>6676</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>6619</td></tr>
```

So, if I'm in third row, where I've an id say for eg. 6676,

When I click on some row, say 3rd row, I'll get the second td using `find("td:eq(1)").text()`,

now I need to get the next row second td value, it means I need to get "6614", which means I need to get the next row after 6676 of current row i.e. 3rd row.. when I try to get it using

Here say currentMysqlId = 6676 I get on clicking on 3rd row. I need to get it row wise

```
var nextMySqlId = $('#tblInbox tbody tr td:contains('+currentMysqlId+')').parent("tr").next("tr").find("td:eq(6)").text();
```

I'm getting stupid answers because if I search for 6676 in the table, it has many rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want it on click? Or you want a function that finds an `id` and then gets the next row?

Comment: Exact Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800380/get-next-row-td-value-of-matched-td-value-of-a-particular-row-using-jquery/23800415?noredirect=1#comment36615330_23800415

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Qxh2/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it on `click` of a row, which you seem to be asking, then this will work:

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var next = $(this).next();
    var nextId = next ? next.find("td:eq(1)").text() : null;

    console.log(currentId);
    console.log(nextId);
});
```

Note that `nextId` will be `null` if there is no next row.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LavW8/)